# Is it right to update your answer with other people's answers?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Well, I feel a little annoyed by this.

I wrote a new answer to a question, that fixed the most upvoted question, wich was wrong for the time being.

Then I get some upvotes, but the most voted question "fixes" it with my solution, and I guess I'll never be upvoted again.

This is personal case that highlighted this issue, that must be commom.

Comment: These things happen... I usually don't mind if they give credit to me or the person they borrowed from. I wouldn't say it is wrong if they don't give credit but I frown on it.

Comment: @TronicZomB Technically speaking they're breaking the CC license if they copy-paste without attribution, although in the more trivial questions it's equally likely that they came up with the same solution on their own.

Comment: @Juhana Oh I did not realize that actually! So they should be flagged with... Other? I did have someone copy part of my answer into theirs and since it was copied from mine, it was wrong for their answer and I just called them out on it in the comments since I wasn't sure if they should be flagged.

Comment: @TronicZomB I suppose you could also edit the answer and add the attribution yourself.

Comment: @Juhana I will keep that in mind in the future. I consider the other situation done and over, so not worth it to go back over it, but thanks for the tip!

Comment: What's [more annoying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172640/dealing-with-quickly-edited-copied-answers) is when someone posts a quick poor-quality answer, waits for someone else to post a better-quality answer, then edits their own answer to basically say the same thing.

Comment: its a possible up vote from me to the person who fixed their answer even if im the one pointing out the error ( it remains in the comments )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's a good idea to fix your answer if there is a mistake in it, whether it's a mistake you noticed or a mistake that someone else noticed.

If you point out a mistake in someone's answer you should *want* them to fix it; that should be a goal of you pointing out their mistake.  You shouldn't be calling someone out just to shame them without any expectation of them fixing the error.

Fixing the answer ensures that the highly upvoted answer at the top of the list is correct; rather than forcing viewers to read several answers down the list, or to read through a bunch of comments, in order to find out that it's not working or how to fix it.  Remember that the primary goal here at SO/SE is creating a useful repository of information; editing the answer as was done here absolutely helps accomplish that.

Comment: I agree with you. This is indeed better for someone to find the answer fast, but it is annoying for the contributors.

Comment: @JúlioTurollaRibeiro And I'm saying it shouldn't be.  You should be *glad* that someone noticed your comment about the problem(s) with their answer and corrected it, not upset.  You should be upset if they *don't* fix their answer.